# backbone router several root, how to load this properly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, backbone-routing

I'm missing something here. My problem is very simple I think.
mysite.com/app and mysite.com/transaction both load a different html page but they load the same router.

For each case I need my router to be written in order than
mysite.com/app/#/someparams triggers 'app' function
mysite.com/transaction/#/someparams triggers 'transaction' function. (With or without # I don't care but this is the way it works for me =/ )

If I write :

```
routes: {
    'app':'app',
    'app/:params':'app',
    'transaction':'transaction',
    'transaction/:params': 'transaction'
}

Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true 
});
```

Then mysite.com/app/#/params or mysite.com/transaction/#/params won't trigger the wanted functions.

If I write this:

```
     Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: false,
        root:'/app'
    });
```

then parameters will be ok for /app but not for /transaction. What to do ? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple but I'm kinda confused right now ..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is only expecting a single parameter in both the routes that you have defined.

`mysite.com/app/#/params`
  matches  `app/:params` The `#` is being passed in as a parameter here.

Also the hash should be preceding the route map.

`mysite.com#app/params` This would match the route expected by backbone as per your map.

You could just use 2 routes using the optional feature.

```
routes: {
    'app(/:params)':'app',
    'transaction(/:params)':'transaction'
}
```

Comment: true but then the wrong html is loaded. mysite.com => landing , mysite.com/app => app , mysite.com/transaction => transaction ... Any idea how to roganize this ?

Comment: you mean app(/*)  ? otherwise regexp error is triggered, however when I use app(/*) my paramters are not passed ... app:fucntion(params) { ... gives me null params when I try app/#/wtv

Comment: it seems I have the same issue than that : https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/810 , so basically I would have to point /app and /transaction with the same root, something like /tool/#/app & tool/#/transaction

what do you think ?